# pagespeed проверяет старую версию сайта

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы, pagespeed-insights, pagespeed

Уже более 12 часов https://pagespeed.web.dev/ проверяет одну и ту же старую версию. Грузит элементы, которые удалены или заменены. Как можно повлиять на это?
При этом, до этого, он работал исправно. То есть, я проверял работу сайта там и всё было хорошо до какого-то момента.
Сайт на WP. Отключал плагины кеширования, ставил Hello world вместо всего сайта - ничего не "пушит" его.

Comment: добавить аргументы в адресную строку, которые не влияют на страницу?  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Этот кеш на стороне гугла

Comment: Посмотрите еще, возможно sitemap не обновились